# Accordion not working properly, it should be open one at a time

Tags: angular

In my Angular application I have created an accordion, the expected behavior should be, if one is open remaining all should be closed, but my accordion is not working as per the expectation, at a time multiple panels can be open.

**TEMPLTATE:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let items of moduleGroup; let i = index">
  <button class="accordion" id={{i}} (click)="toggleAccordian($event, i)">{{items.moduleGroupName}}</button>
  <div class="panel">
      <p *ngFor="let modules of items.moduleList"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="getRoleModulePermissionById($event,modules.id)">{{modules.moduleName}}</a> </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**COMPONENT**

```js
toggleAccordian(event, index) {
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.acc.length; i++) {
        console.log("acc i",this.acc[i])
        this.acc[i].click = function() {
        if(index==this.acc[i].id){
            console.log("index",index)
            this.displayBreadCrumbText = null
            this.moduleNameStr = null;
            this.moduleGroupText=event.target.innerText;
            console.log("this.moduleGroupText",this.moduleGroupText)
            var element = event.target;
            console.log("element event",event)
            console.log("element",element)
            const x = element.classList.toggle('active');
            console.log("x",x)
            const panel = element.nextElementSibling;
            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
            }
            
        }
      }
    }
    
}
```

While inspecting I figured it out that there is an `acitve` class which will be dynamically appended when I clicked on an accordion, what I am trying to do is, while clicking on another accordion I want to remove the `active` class from previously opened accordion, but I am not able to reach out there, please help me out.

Comment: please create a working sample on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: I am not much used of that, it sounds new for me, could you please do me a favor, if you can please create stackblitz for the same, as I have already posted the code which is written my ts and template, it is part of POC, thank you

Comment: use `[ngClass]="activeId==i"`and  `(click)="activeId=i"` in your .html. In Angular you should use "variables" to change the class of one element. I know that javascript is great but the philosofy of Angular is relationate variable in .ts with how you see your aplication in .html

Comment: tried this approach too, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set all `maxHeight` to null before to show corresponding section.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("panel")).forEach((t:any)=>{
  if(t != element.nextElementSibling)
     t.style.maxHeight = null
})
```

So `toggleAccordian` function would be like this:

toggleAccordian(event, index) {
const element = event.target;

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("panel")).forEach((t:any)=>{
  if(t != element.nextElementSibling)
     t.style.maxHeight = null
})

element.classList.toggle("active");

const panel = element.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

}
}

And the HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of moduleGroup; let i = index">
    <button class="accordion" id=Id{{i}} (click)="toggleAccordian($event, i);">
      {{items.moduleGroupName}}</button>
    <div class="panel"  >
        <p *ngFor="let modules of items.moduleList" > 
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="getRoleModulePermissionById($event,modules.id)">{{modules.moduleName}}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is working sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-demo-app-w5yzpy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks for the update, but the problem is accordion is not closing if once open, i tried to close the same accordion after open, but it is not closing

Comment: @user9634982 I put working sample for you on stackblitz.com. what is wrong with that? let me know if it is not working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-demo-app-y7csi6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: expand the first accordion and try to collapse the same, it won't collapsed, it will only collapsed until and unless I haven't expand second accordian

Comment: @user9634982 I updated my answer. Now you can open and close the same section

Comment: I've wrote your code under a "more Angular approach". Really I don't like so much use document.elementGetById, or toogleClass or another javascript aproach if I can do it the same using a simple "variable"

Comment: Kindly share your approach too, thank you

Answer (score 1):

An Angular approach based in the response proposed:

You declare a variable in your .ts

```
  activeIndex:number=-1;
```

And create a simple .html

```
<div *ngFor="let items of moduleGroup; let i = index">
  <button class="accordion" id=Id{{i}} [class.active]="i==activeIndex" 
         (click)="activeIndex=activeIndex==i?-1:i">
          {{items.moduleGroupName}}
  </button>
  <div #panel class="panel" 
    [style.max-height]="activeIndex!=i?0:panel.scrollHeight+'px'">
    <p *ngFor="let modules of items.moduleList">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
           (click)="getRoleModulePermissionById($event,modules.id)">
           {{modules.moduleName}}
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, I made the same without use `document.elementByClass` or toogle class instead

I use

```
`[class.active]="activeIndex==i"`
```

This make that the element get the class active if the variable "activeIndex" is equal to i

And

```
[style.max-height]="activeIndex!=i?0:panel.scrollHeight+'px'"
```

This make that the element change his property [style.max-heigth] according the variable. See that to get the "scrollHeight" I use a template reference variable "panel" -see the `#panel` in the div.

The expresion is a simple ternary operator, if a condition `ativeIndex!=i` happens, the value is `0` else `panel.scrollHeigth+'px'`

(You can use also [ngClass] or [ngStyle], see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#built-in-attribute-directives)

Well the "click" is a bit complex

```
(click)="activeIndex=activeIndex==i?-1:i"
```

If is yet active, the activeIndex is equal to -1, else is equal to i (remember that the i=0 is the first panel, i=1 is the second one...)

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-accordion-demo-app-eazkna?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) (forked from the solution proposed)

Comment: I must say, the above one is the totally Angular based approach.

Comment: very clean, elegant and properly descripted one, thanks @Eliseo